# relative entropy, Fisher information, and metric slope for non-convex domains

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mg.metric-geometry, calculus-of-variations, optimal-transportation

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$ If $\Omega\subset \R^d$ is a convex domain it is well-known that the relative entropy
$$
\mathcal H(\rho)=
\int_{\Omega}\rho\log\rho \ \mathrm{d}x 
\qquad  \mbox{for }\rho=\rho(x)\cdot \mathrm{d}x
$$
(and set to $+\infty$ if $\rho$ is not absolutely continuous)
is $0$-displacement convex for the quadratic Wasserstein interpolation in the sense of R. McCann.
Let me denote $\mathcal W=\mathcal W_2$ this quadratic Wasserstein distance.
In this very setting, the local metric slope
$$
|\partial \mathcal H|(\rho)=\limsup\limits_{\nu\to\rho}\frac{\left[\mathcal H(\rho)-\mathcal H(\nu)\right]^+}{\mathcal W(\rho,\nu)}
$$
is known to coincide with the (square-root of the) Fisher information
$$
|\partial \mathcal H|^2(\rho)
=\mathcal I(\rho) :=
\int_{\Omega} |\nabla\log \rho(x)|^2\rho(x)\mathrm{d}x
$$
(again suitably set to be $+\infty$ if whenever $\rho$ is not smooth enough for the above formula to be meaningful).
This can be found e.g. in [1], Chapter 10 and in particular Theorems 10.4.6 and 10.4.9 in the whole space. The case of a convex domain is treated in section 10.4.7, simply adding a potential energy $\mathcal V(\rho)=\int_{\R^d}V(x)\ \rho(dx)$ for the convex indicator $V=V_\Omega$ of $\Omega$ (i.e. $V(x)=0$ if $x\in\Omega$ and $V(x)=+\infty$ else, indeed a convex function if and only if $\Omega$ is itself a convex domain).
The proof deeply relies on some $\lambda$- geodesic (displacement) convexity of the functional considered therein (of the more general *internal energy* class), here in my particular case $\lambda=0$ since my entropy $\mathcal H$ is computed relatively to the Lebesgue measure.

---

> **Question:** can anybody provide a reference for the statement that $|\partial \mathcal H|^2=\mathcal I$ when the domain $\Omega$ is still smooth and bounded but possibly non-convex?

---

Formally the result should still hold, e.g. differentiating the entropy $\left.\frac{d\mathcal H(\rho_t)}{dt}\right|_{t=0}$ along the heat flow $\partial_t\rho_t=\Delta\rho_t$ started from $\rho_0=\rho$.
Note however that non-convexity of the domains may destroy any modulus of displacement convexity, i.e. the entropy becomes $-\infty$-convex (or rather, cannot be $\lambda$-convex for any $\lambda0$ - even very negative). As a consequence many argument in Ambrosio-Gigli-Savaré's proofs [1] completely collapse.

To see that the geodesic convexity is destroyed, take e.g. a smooth banana-shaped domain $\Omega$, with two smooth probability densities $\rho_0,\rho_1$ conveniently supported on very small balls near each of the endpoints of the banana. It is not hard to cook-up the banana (eheheh!) so that for intermediate times, say $t=1/2$, the geodesic interpolation $\rho_{1/2}$ must be supported on the boundary (see my childish picture attached).[image]

As a consequence $\rho_{1/2}$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue (volume) measure, hence $\mathcal H(\rho_{1/2})=+\infty$ although $\mathcal H(\rho_0),\mathcal H(\rho_1)<+\infty$ and therefore $\mathcal H$ cannot be $\lambda$-convex.

[1] Ambrosio, L., Gigli, N., & Savaré, G. (2005). Gradient flows: in metric spaces and in the space of probability measures. Springer Science & Business Media.

Comment: Ambrosio, Gigli and Savaré (Theorem 7.6 in their 2014 Inventiones paper) have shown that $\lvert \partial\mathcal H\rvert^2=\mathcal I$ if and only if $\lvert \partial\mathcal H\rvert$ is sequentially lower semicontinuous w.r.t. strong convergence in $P_2(\Omega)$. I don't know if this is known to hold for all bounded smooth Euclidean domains.

Comment: @MaoWao thank you for your comment, this is actually helpful. unfortunately the lower semi-continuity seems hard to check a priori, without an explicit representation for the slope (which is precisely what I'm trying to get to). thanks anyway